# How to use ImageMagick convert command for all images in subfolders

Tags: linux, image, optimization, imagemagick, bulk

For single files, I am using the following ImageMagick commands (as google [suggests](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages)):

**For png**

```
convert file.png -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace PNG -colorspace sRGB file.png
```

**For jpg**

```
convert file.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace sRGB file.jpg
```

But I need to do the same for all .jpg in a subfolder

I tried this:

```
find ./*.jpg | xargs convert $ -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace sRGB $
```

And all the images where compressed but named with the name of the first one with an added index, example:

```
/img/first-one-0.jpg  
/img/first-one-1.jpg  
/img/first-one-2.jpg  
/img/first-one-3.jpg  
...
```

How could I do It in bulk overriding originals? Even if we have multiple sub-dirs:

```
/img/dir-1/one.jpg  
...  
/img/dir-2/foo.jpg
```

Comment: Walk through the dirs, and execute the command line. I prefer to use Python.

Comment: @ausk I am using linux and I have not much experience using the command line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to overwrite all the files in a directory, use `mogrify`:

```
mogrify -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace PNG -colorspace sRGB *.png
```

If you want the results written in a new sub-directory called `processed`:

```
mkdir processed
mogrify -path processed ...
```

---

If you are on **ImageMagick** v7 or newer, that becomes:

```
mkdir processed
magick mogrify -path processed ...
```

Comment: I changed the last bit to `*/*.png` so it processes all images in subfolders (one level)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> (1) Save as `cvt.py`
>
> (2) Open terminal, run `python3 cvt.py your_images_root_path`

---

> Notice: The following code may modify your images in place, test it first.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018/05/15 20:30:52
# 2018/05/15 20:41:04

## save as cvt.py
## run `python3 cvt.py your_images_root_path` in Terminal


import os
import sys 

def convert(fname): 
    _, ext = os.path.split(fname)
    ext = ext.upper()
    if ext in (".JPEG", ".JPG"):
        fname = "JPG"
    elif ext == ".PNG":
        fname = "PNG"
    else:
        return 
    cmd =  "convert {fname} -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace {} -colorspace sRGB {fname}".format(fname=fname, fmt=fmt)    
    os.system(cmd)

    ## Debug info 
    print(cmd)


def convert_in_dir(root_dir):
    assert os.path.exists(root_dir)
    for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(root_dir):   
        fnames = [os.path.join(dpath, fname) for fname in fnames]
        for fname in fnames:
            convert(fname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root_path= sys.argv[1]
    convert_in_dir(root_path)
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I assume I have to place this in to a file. What extension should it have and how shall I execute it? Thanks

Comment: I get this error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cvt.py", line 31, in <module>
    root_path= sys.argv[1]
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined" Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to  add  `import sys`, See my update.

Comment: I added it, now doesn't fire any errrors but i don't see any file changed/created

Comment: Update with debug info again. Try to see any output info?